# Android: How to create a stylish listview as in Youtube application

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, youtube

I'm using Android Studio to create an application that has a listview, and after I selected my project to be using navigation drawer I added a listview control to my activity.

I looked over the internet and the available examples about customizing the listview row is not what I needed, I need to create items / rows as in Youtube application with rounded corners and shades and bigger space between items.

Is this a listview control with customized rows or it's an activity with compound controls (As items / rows) and vertical scrollbar?

[Screenshot from Youtube application]

[image]

Edit 1:

Here is my code using @Saeed approach, but I'm facing a little problem; using Shape Stroke to have a left/right/top/bottom margins leads to have the double size of top/bottom margin between two list items. How can I set each edge margin individually?

[image]

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">

<!-- icon -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    />

<!-- title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_counter"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<!-- counter -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_counter"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

background_with_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#C8C8C8" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <!-- Not needed anymore after using padding and divider in ListView-->
            <!-- <stroke android:width="20dp"/> -->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="0.5dp" android:left="0.5dp" android:top="0.5dp" android:bottom="1.5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <!-- Not needed anymore after using padding and divider in ListView-->
            <!-- <stroke android:width="20dp"/> -->
            <padding android:left="7dp" android:right="7dp"
                     android:top="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
```

Edit 2:

The answer to my question in Edit 1 is solved by adding (To my ListView) android:divider="10dp" to control the vertical space between items, and using android:padding="10dp" to have the same space on the left/right of all items and on the top/bottom of the first and last items. and using android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" to avoid having the vertical scrollbar overlaying the list items. and I removed stroke android:width="20dp" from background_with_shadow.xml

**I'm going to test @Shubhang Malviya approach and add the results here later.**

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) , here is the [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) , it will create UI like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By adding style to your layouts you can round them

Define this in drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

and add above style to the backround of your layout

```
android:background="@drawable/your_above_syle"
```

Another way is adding 9 patch images to the background of your layouts for example using this image which can round and add shadow to your layouts

[image: 9 patch sample image]